# Do you have the source for the quote about not trusting liars

Tags: tanach, commentaries, quotations

Does anyone remember a quote about how once someone is a confirmed liar nothing they say or said can be trusted and should be questioned?
I cannot find the exact words.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, @Adam49!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Sanhedrin 89b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sanhedrin.89b.13?lang=bi):

> כך עונשו של בדאי שאפילו אמר אמת אין שומעין לו
>
> [T]his is the punishment of the liar, that even if he speaks the truth, others do not listen to him.